# ¿Desactivar la propiedad GET de vue?

Tags: vue.js, get, component

Necesitaba un component que me hiciera lo que hace este componente 
https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/examples/#distraction-free

Utilice el ultimo ejemplo "Raw number value with directive"

Como verán, cuando escribes un numero en automático se remueve el formato y deja escribir libremente, y cuando dejas de escribir el formato regresa.

En lo que estoy haciendo es algo parecido, solo que tengo agregado un

un get dentro de computed

```
computed: {
    cv: {
      get: function() {
          return 0; (Este no es el codigo que tengo dentro)
       },
      set: function(a) {
      }
    }
```

Mi problema esta en que cuada vez que escribo un numero, el metodo get se manda a llamar y hace que automaticamente mi campo tome el formato, ejemplo, si pongo

"3", apenas lo escribo y lo cambia a "3.00", y si quiero agregar otro numero, tengo que salirme del campo y volver a dar click en el para que se muestre  "3" de nuevo. Me percate que el problema esta dentro del "get", ¿Alguna forma de solucionarlo? De hecho, ese get, solo lo ocupo una vez, cuando recien se entra a la pantalla,  ese get agarra lo que viene del model y hace algunos procesos, pero solo lo uso una vez.

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código completo de tu computed?, tal vez así sea más claro el problema.

Comment: Porque usar get ya que esto es reactivo cada vez que escribas se ejecutará tal vez el evento v-on:change es lo que buscas

Comment: Si quieres ejecutar algo solo una vez puedes poner una variable booleana en falso y preguntar que si es falso se ejecute algo y dentro de eso lo estableces a verdadero y ya no se ejecutará nunca más